# Swift generics and subclasses

Tags: arrays, swift, generics

my question might be simple, but it got me puzzled a bit: 
Imagine I have an array of different objects which all have a common parent class     "`MyClass`".

```
var values = [MyClass]()
```

However they all have their specific subclass like for example "`MyClassSubclass`".

```
values.append(MyClassSubclass())
```

I now want to create a generic method returning me the first object inside this array which is of type `MyClassSubclass`. I would like to prevent casting the object, but instead have a generic method which takes the subclass object as T parameter and returns me the first occurrence of subclass T inside this array.

I thought of something like this (but surely that does not work):

```
func getFirst<T: MyClass>(_ ofType : T.Type) -> T?
```

I guess I'm just stuck and I don't know what to search for, so if someone could help me I would greatly appreciate it.

**Edit** *Example based on the above values:*

```
class MyClass {}
class MyClassSubclass : MyClass {}
class MyClassSubclass2 : MyClass{}

var values = [MyClass]()
values.append(MyClassSubclass())
values.append(MyClassSubclass2())

//Return the first class element appearing here as a subclass type
func getFirst<T>(_ ofType : T.Type) -> T?{}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One approach is to iterate over the array and use optional binding
to check if an element is of the given type:

```
func getFirst<T: MyClass>(ofType: T.Type) -> T? {
    for elem in values {
        if let item = elem as? T {
            return item
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

This can be simplified using `for case` with the `as` pattern:

```
func getFirst<T: MyClass>(ofType: T.Type) -> T? {
    for case let item as T in values {
        return item
    }
    return nil
}
```

Another approach is to use `flatMap` to find all items of the given 
type and return the first one:

```
func getFirst<T: MyClass>(ofType: T.Type) -> T? {
    return values.flatMap { $0 as? T }.first
}
```

If the array can be large and you want to avoid the creation of an
intermediate array then you can use `lazy`:

```
func getFirst<T: MyClass>(ofType: T.Type) -> T? {
    return values.lazy.flatMap { $0 as? T }.first
}
```

As an array extension method this would be

```
extension Array {
    func getFirst<T>(ofType: T.Type) -> T? {
        return flatMap { $0 as? T }.first
    }
}
```

Comment: I like your approach. Which one you think would be the fastest to return the first occurrence?

Comment: @binloan: My guess would be that the for-loops are the fastest, one would have to to measure and compare. But I would recommend to check first if the performance of this part is crucial to your app. If the arrays are not large then I doubt that there will be much difference.

Comment: Okay I will test that. My arrays currently are not large, but this might happen in the future and I would like to have a proper implementation.

Comment: +1 for the comprehensive answer. And @binloan, the for loops would probably be the faster (on average), since the `flatMap`s don't short circuit the operation.

Comment: @xoudini: `lazy.flatMap` returns a "lazy collection", so that would short-circuit, but it has more overhead. So  it depends on the array size.

Answer (score 2):

If you'd like to use global function, which is not recommended, try this

```
func getFirst<T>(ofType: T.Type) -> T? where T: MyClass {
  for value in values where value is T {
    return value as? T
  }
  return nil
}

let first = getFirst(ofType: MyClassSubclass2.self)
```

The first answer should be better for Swift.

Comment: This looks rather smooth even though the "?" cast will be slower than if you used the "if let " structure. But why in your opinion this function is not recommended?

Comment: mainly because it's not elegant for reusing , the "extension array" is better

Answer (score 1):

This feels a bit like abuse of generics, but here's an extension:

```
extension Array where Element == MyClass {
    func getFirst<T>(_ ofType: T.Type) -> T? {
        return self.first(where: { ofType == type(of: $0) }) as? T
    }
}
```

The method can then be called as `let first = values.getFirst(MyClassSubclass.self)`.

I'd personally prefer simply casting inline for clarity:

```
let first = values.first(where: { type(of: $0) == MyClassSubclass.self }) as? MyClassSubclass
```

Comment: I like the extension way however to clarify this. It will be part of a touch framework where a framework user shall be able to easily retrieve the first instance of an object type. That's why I want this. So extensions would be bad because of the needed public scope. Also your second approach would not work because it moves the load to the framework user (am I right?) -

Comment: Why would extensions be bad in a framework? A lot of frameworks use extensions of built-in Swift and UIKit types.