# checking if scene contains nodes of specific type

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

In my SKScene, I want to check if there are any nodes that are of a specific type. And because I need something like this multiple times, I was trying to create the following function, that takes a type as a function, but it doesn't compile, any help please?

```
extension SKNode {
    func containsObject(ofType type: Any) -> Bool {
        return children.contains(where {$0 is type}) ? true : false
    }  
}
```

The error:

> Use of undeclared type 'type'

Comment: What is the error you receive? Is children defined anywhere? Also, there is a typo in your function name, it should be `containsObject...`

Comment: @DávidPásztor Edited

Comment: You need to make the function generic, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45629593/swift-generics-and-subclasses for an example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make your function a generic function and check the generic type parameter instead of the input argument.

```
extension SKNode{
    func containsObject<T>(ofType: T.Type) -> Bool {
        return children.contains(where: {$0 is T})
    }
}
```

This is, how you call it:

```
let node  = SKNode()

class MyNode: SKNode {
    var title = ""
}

let myNode = MyNode()
node.addChild(myNode)

node.containsObject(ofType: MyNode.self) //returns true

let otherNode = SKNode()
otherNode.addChild(SKNode())    
otherNode.containsObject(ofType: MyNode.self) //returns false
```

Comment: @JuicyFruit I don't know how did you test it, but check my updated answer with an example, it is returning true.

Comment: yeah, my bad, you do `T.Type`, I do `type(of: $0)`, didn't notice at first.

Comment: `? true : false` is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

why do not you use array functions like this?

```
let a: [AnyObject] = ["a" as AnyObject]

if a.contains(where: {$0 is String}) {
    print("a")
}
```

example with `SKNode`

```
class MyNode: SKNode {

}

let a = SKNode()

a.children.contains(where: ({$0 is MyNode}))

a.addChild(MyNode())

a.children.contains(where: ({$0 is MyNode}))
```

wrapped

```
extension SKNode {
    func containsObject<T>(ofType type: T) -> Bool {
        return self.children.contains(where: ({type(of: $0) is T})) ? true : false
    }  
}

class MyNode: SKNode {

}

let a = SKNode()

a.containsObject(ofType: MyNode.self)

a.addChild(MyNode())

a.containsObject(ofType: MyNode.self)
```

Comment: This is perfect, but i want to imbed that in a function, as shown in the question

Comment: @Fayyouz added wrapper

Comment: Okayy, ill try it